# Scraping text within several span tags (Ruby & Nokogiri)

Tags: ruby, parsing, web-scraping, nokogiri

I am trying to scrape "Description" from this HTML structure

```
<div class="menu-index-page__item-content">
 <h6 class="menu-index-page__item-title">
  <span> Item title </span>
 </h6>
 <p class="menu-index-page__item-desc">
  <span>
   <span>
    <span>Description</span>
   </span>
  </span>
```

Each tag has an element with it that I don't know how to handle:

```
data-reactid=".3wrqgx5340.3.5.0.4:$523105.2.$3959254.$menuItemContent.1.0"
```

Each data-reactid is different. So if I target this attribute I will scrape stuff I don't want.

I've tried `.search` `.xpath`, using tags and classes but nothing seems to work.

Is there a way to say: give me the p tag that has a class="menu-index-page__item-desc" and scrape the 3rd span from there?

Comment: Description string continue to change? You can use WATIR to do this Job? When you execute the code it will print what in the place description lies.

Comment: If you are ready to WATIR, let me know.

Comment: That's all stuff that gets added to the dom by React. So you need Watir or similar anyway for this.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I looked into WATIR and it looks like a good solution thank you! how can apply it in my case?

Comment: refer WATIR here `http://watir.com/guides/` In your case, you can write `b.p(class: 'menu-index-page__item-desc').span.span.span.text`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required value via xpath
 `//text()[contains(.,'Description')]`

You code and xpath:
[image: xpath]